# What is the relationship between the manifest correlation between ranked variables and the latent, continuous correlation?

Tags: correlation, expected-value, pearson-r, ranks, polychoric

Suppose you draw n pairs of observations from a real-valued bivariate distribution. You then convert each observation to its ascending rank order. Given the population correlation for the real-valued distribution, what is the expected correlation between the ranked variables?

A possible solution, which I haven't been able to track down, is a parametric model for the polychoric correlation on ranks.

Comment: The population Spearman correlation depends only on the copula of the joint distribution while the population Pearson correlation depends on the joint distribution which also involves the marginal distributions.

Comment: I was actually looking for something more computational, which I think I found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423594/spearman-rho-as-a-function-of-pearson-r. I'll be deleting this question as redundant.

Comment: That's *specifically* for the bivariate normal, of which there is no hint in your question. You say 'a real valued bivariate distribution', so clearly while you were considering distribution, you did not choose to restrict it to that case. The only reason such a specific functional relationship was possible was because specifying bivariate normal is one way to supply the missing information spelled out in my initial comment.